# How to access RegExp.prototype.exec() return value?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array I want to pull all the files that end in `.txt`, so I apply a regular expression to find all that match within

```
var x = ["test.txt", "random.txt", "dontgetme"]
var re = RegExp(".*\.txt", "g")
```

When I try to access the results via the first index, I can retrieve the correct result:

`re.exec(x)[0]` returns `"test.txt,random.txt"`

but when I try to store it in a variable, I can't access it anymore:

`var y = re.exec(x)[0]` returns `undefined`

How do I store the results of the `.exec` in a variable to be accessed at a later time?

Comment: @webbm no it won't. It's joining the array into a single string, and matching all of the characters up to the last `.txt`.

Comment: FYI, you'll want to escape your period in the .txt, otherwise it will match any character, so btxt.exe will match

Comment: And maybe close the string and parens in the example code.

Comment: @PeterLaBanca how do you escape a period in the .txt?

Comment: add a leading slash before the period. for example: RegExp(".*\.txt", "g")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`, `.test()`

```
var re = /\.txt$/;
var matches = x.filter(function(text) { return re.test(text) })
```

Comment: I think the regex is instantiating on every iteration. Maybe would be better to keep it in a separate variable. Usually the regex is compiled at RegExp construction time and that operation costs time.

Comment: @andreim Or convert array to string and use `.match()`

Answer (score 1):

> `var y = re.exec(x)[0]` returns `undefined`

This is because you're looking at the return value of a `var` statement, which always returns undefined.

You want to assign it to `y` and then access `y`, as such:

```
var y = re.exec(x)[0] // always undefined
console.log(y) // ok!
```

Comment: *"This is because you're doing an assignment, which always returns undefined."* No, assignments only result in `undefined` if you're assigning `undefined`. `var` statements, on the other hand, always result in `undefined` (something you can only observe in a REPL environment).

Answer (score 0):

> but when I try to store it in a variable, I can't access it anymore:
>
> ```
> var y = re.exec(x)[0] returns undefined
> ```

You'll only see that in a REPL environment (like the console). `var` statements result in `undefined`. But `y` will have the value.

If you pass `x` directly into `exec`, it'll be coerced to string, and you'll end up with `"test.txt,random.txt,dontgetme"`.

Also note that you don't want that `g` flag, and you *do* want to escape the `.` in `.txt`. There's no need for `new RegExp` here, just use the literal form: `/.*\.txt/`.

Instead of passing `x` into `exec`, to get results for each of those, use a loop of some kind. For instance, here I'm using `map` to create an array of the results. Inside `map`, I use `[0]` to access just the first thing in the array `exec` returns, as that's the only useful thing it returns for your regex:

```js
var x = ["test.txt", "random.txt", "dontgetme"]
var re = /.*\.txt/;
var result = x.map(function(entry) {
  var match = re.exec(entry);
  return match ? match[0] : null;
});
console.log(result);
```